# replace values in row if it matches with last row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have below data frame in R

```
df <- read.table(text = "
        A   B   C   D    E
                 14  6   8   16  14
                 5   6   10  6   4
                 2   4   6   3   4
                 26  6   18  39  36
                 1   2   3   1   2
                 3   1   1   1   1
                 3   5   1   4   11
                 ", header = TRUE)
```

Now if values in last two rows are same, I need to replace these values with 0, can any one help me in this if it is doable in R

For example:
values last two rows in column 1 are 3 so I need to replace 3 by 0.
Also same for column 3 last two rows in column 3 are 1 so I need to replace 3 by 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can compare last 2 rows and replace in the columns where the values are same :

```
nr <- nrow(df)
df[(nr-1):nr, df[nr-1, ]==df[nr, ]] <- 0

df
#   A B  C  D  E
#1 14 6  8 16 14
#2  5 6 10  6  4
#3  2 4  6  3  4
#4 26 6 18 39 36
#5  1 2  3  1  2
#6  0 1  0  1  1
#7  0 5  0  4 11
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to loop through the columns, check `if` the last two elements (`tail(x,2)`) or duplicated, then `replace` it with 0 or `else` return the column and assign the output back to the dataset.  The `[]` make sure that the structure is intact.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) if(anyDuplicated(tail(x, 2))>0) 
                 replace(x, c(length(x)-1, length(x)), 0) else x)
df
#   A B  C  D  E
#1 14 6  8 16 14
#2  5 6 10  6  4
#3  2 4  6  3  4
#4 26 6 18 39 36
#5  1 2  3  1  2
#6  0 1  0  1  1
#7  0 5  0  4 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this:

```
r <- tail(df, 2)
r[,r[1,]==r[2,]] <- 0
df <- rbind(head(df, -2), r)
```